# Automate package installation on android

Tags: android, automation

I know this will sound strange and maybe even a bit counter intuitive. But I need a way to tell android to download additional assets (Images etc.) and place them in a specific directory for my application to use. Right now, because of how the app is designed, Our customers have to download the app and the additional resources and then move things around in the file system to make everything work properly. These additional resources are customer dependent, so they cant be baked into the application. We also need to maintain control over these things (The app itself I don't have control over).

One of my first thoughts was to use flashable archives to deliver the resources and apk file. But I dont really think that would be any easier for users. My other idea is to write an "Installation app" that would download all the required files and then download and install the apk for the "real" application.

I'm not looking for any full blown solutions here. Just some other ideas to try out. In the end I want my users to be able to click one link on our download page and and have everything they need set up for them, rather than them having to manually move stuff around.

Comment: IMHO all ur proposed solutions seem bad to me. I would have the app on first open ask the user which version he wishes to use and after selection handle all the download logic to an internal app folder by code. In case is a variant list of possible versions, create on the server side an endpoint that the app can query for the available versions.

Comment: @Budius I agree, they're not optimal. Your suggestion is what I would prefer to do. However, as I said, I don't have control over the application. So I have to get creative.

Comment: so you're not the developer of the application? So you cannot directly change how the application is coded? If yes, to those questions, I believe in your question is not relevant to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Budius I'm sorry you feel that way. I would ask that you keep comments constructive in nature. Thank you.